# Searching on an Enum Field with Ransack

Tags: ruby, ransack

I've got a table, 'jobs' with a enum field 'status'.  status has the following enum set:

```
enum status: [ :draft, :active, :archived ]
```

using ransack, how do I filter the table for, say, all active records?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can declare own ransacker in model like this:

```
ransacker :status, formatter: proc {|v| statuses[v]} do |parent|
  parent.table[:status]
end
```

Then You can use default ransack syntax `_eq` to check equality like this:

```
Model.ransack(status_eq: 'active').result
```

Edit: If column name doesn't change you can skip block of code:

```
ransacker :status, formatter: proc {|v| statuses[v]}
```

Comment: Thanks.  that works, but it seems like i might as well just use the param value and do a regular search.  the code reads a bit better / simple that way.  Adding a filter in ActiveAdmin worked without creating a ransacker, even though they use Ransack for their filtering.  It seems odd it didn't work on the front end as easily.

Comment: @Will Yeap, you can use just simple scope. It should work fine :) But problem appears when You can't skip using ransack. Without code mentioned above, it's going to always cast parameter `active` to integer `.to_i` so You will get always `0` instead of proper value.

Comment: after googling and reading your comments, you may combine, but there could be issues when using arel.group,

Model.active.ransack(params_for_others) works. I'll write an answer

Answer (score 9):

This is something I use in my views for enums and ransack:

```
<%= f.select :status_eq, Model.statuses.to_a.map { |w| [w[0].humanize, w[1]] },
                         {:include_blank => true} %>
```

Comment: So it appears then that you must pass the integer value of attribute to the q hash, since ransack will not do the enum conversation for you.

Comment: Any idea how to make it as `radio_buttons`?

Answer (score 1):

Below works fine for all cases :draft, 'draft', 0, '0' in model

```
ransacker :status do |parent|
  parent.table[:status]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

ransacker in accepted answer of @qarol works but since OP is looking for a cleaner solution, you may also opt to combine enum defined scopes with ransack like the following:

```
Model.active.ransack(params_for_others).result
Model.not_active.ransack(params_for_others).result
```

These works properly.

You may check with: `puts Model.active.ransack(onboarded_eq: true).result.to_sql`
will print:

```
SELECT "model".* FROM "models" WHERE "models"."status" = 1 AND "users"."onboarded" = TRUE
```

however, beware of some issues when combining ransack + arel,
e.g. GroupingError

```
PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column \"other_model.id\" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function
```